# Can a minor be granted power of attorney?

Tags: united-states, california, oregon, power-of-attorney

Can an adult grant power of attorney to a minor and be bound by contracts signed by the minor on his/her behalf?

Answer (score -2):

In the US, a minor generally cannot enter into a contract and thus is ineligible to be given a power of attorney.

[ABA](https://www.americanbar.org/groups/real_property_trust_estate/resources/estate_planning/power_of_attorney/)

> There are no special qualifications necessary for someone to act as an
> attorney-in-fact except that the person must not be a minor or
> otherwise incapacitated. The best choice is someone you trust.
> Integrity, not financial acumen, is often the most important trait of
> a potential agent.

Comment: Your first sentence is wrong. I see minors buying train tickets and coffee all the time so clearly they can enter contracts.

Comment: Minors can and do enter into contracts. It is just that in many (but not all) cases, such contracts are voidable by the minor, so others may be unwilling to contract with a minor in such cases.

Comment: The contracts with minors that are voidable are strictly speaking executory contracts and contracts for luxuries. But the bottom line conclusion on POAs is  basically correct.